# Is there an established standard term for the concept described in the details?

Tags: terminology, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

If $N$ is a finite set of points in the 2-D Euclidean space, then let ${\tt ch}(N)$ denote the convex hull of $N$, and let
$$
\partial {\tt ch}(N)
$$
denote the boundary of that convex hull.  I need to operate with the subset of $N$ consisting of all those points $x \in N$ that lie on $\partial {\tt ch}(N)$.  For my purposes, it will be convenient to call this subset something; e.g., *the outer layer of $N$*. (I will then define, recursively, *the $k$-th outer layer of $N$*.)  But am I reinventing the terminological wheel?  In other words, does there already exist a standard term for this?

Comment: If $N$ is the minimal set that creates that convex hull which is a [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex) then there are established names for its points: vertex or extreme point. The boundary of the simplex ${\tt ch}(N)$ consists of so called faces. Not sure if that helps. What recursion do you want to consider?

Comment: @KurtG., thanks.  Yes, I thought of "extreme points", but it is not necessarily the case: N can have points that are on the boundary of its convex hull, yet are not extreme.  For example, consider N to consist of (a) the vertices of the unit square, and (b) the midpoints of the sides.  The midpoints will not be extreme points of ch(N).

Recursion: "peel off" the outer layer, take what is left and peel off its outer layer, etc..